# How can I use Twemoji in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, unicode, emoji, twemoji

I just want to render the emojis, whatever is the easiest way. It doesn't necessarily have to replace the entire font pack.  As long as I can render each emoji one by one, that's good enough.